# What is this scabbing and hair loss on my cat's ear?

Tags: cats, health, skin-condition, parasites, hairloss

[image: cat ear w/hair loss&scabs]

Hi my cat is about 4 years old now and something that we just recently came to notice is that he has a bit of scabs and peeling/hair loss on one of his ears. We're not sure what it could be, but we're really worried. I believe this is the first time this has happened. Could it be something like mites? Mange? He doesn't really scratch at it. It is also not red or inflamed, it is just flaking off. If anyone could help me, I would be really thankful.

Comment: Did you happen to figure out what it was? My cat has the exact same thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With that question you better to go to a vet. He will take skin scraping, and  check it in laboratory. 
The treatment will depend on what your cat has, whether it's mange, mites, tinea, food allergy. And don't worry, all these problems are solved easily with correct medicines.

Answer (score 3):

We see a few cats come in like this, could be a number of things like parasites (parasite control always recommended for outdoor pets). If he is outdoors he could have gotten into a scrap with another animal or come in contact with a toxic substance. Could even be the beginning of allergies or ringworm (fungal infection that can be transmitted to people).

It is better to go to your veterinarian just to take a quick peak at his ears (inside and out) and get proper treatment if needed. Skin problems can never be diagnosed online as you need to preform tests to rule out the possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a fungal infection. If the cat is licking excessively and losing hair in patches then it is fungal infection. More commonly known as ringworm. Give your cat medicated anti fungal shampoo and also spray antifungal ingredient.( Lime sulfur and climbazole)
Also give 1 week antibiotic (co-amoxiclav 156.25mg/5ml) of 2ml twice a day.

Comment: Hi welcome to Pets, could you please include some references about this treatment? And generally I'd advise against using antibiotic treatment on oneself and without veterinarian consultation. Thanks.